# Thymeleaf tries to authenticate again when loading template from a controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to render a navigation view from a controller using Thymeleaf. However, the navigation should be based on user's authorities so I do not want to exclude it from Spring Security. I therefore use a UrlTemplateResolver:

```
package it.vertyze.platform.web.controllers;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.UrlTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class VZMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @PostConstruct
    public void templateResolverExtension(){
        UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
        urlTemplateResolver.setOrder(20);
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(urlTemplateResolver);
    }


}
```

However, when I log into my site, the link does not even get resolved. Instead, I am being redirected to the login page. When I disable the security, I get a template not found error, so the template resolver does not render the controller's output, but when I navigate to it, it renders precisely the HTML I want.
Here is my security config:

```
package it.vertyze.platform.web.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class VZWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    VZUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

And here is where I call the link in the enclosing template:

```
<div th:replace="${topNavLinks.getHref()}"></div>
```